# VueJS component: Unable to get render updated collection

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Unable to render updated list on component.
Component is as follow:

```
Vue.component('c-item',{
    data:function(){
    return {
    list: [{id:1,item:'s1'},{id:2,item:'s2'},{id:3,item:'s3'}]
    };
    },
    methods:{
     deleterow: function (id) {
                this.list = this.list.filter(function (i) {
                    return i.id !== id;
                });
                alert(this.list.length);  //lenght is reduced by 1.            
                this.$forceUpdate();  ///explicitly adding this to render UI again.
            },
...
});
```

Comment: You either don't have `deleterow` in the `methods` object of your component, or you aren't providing a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue.

Comment: my mistake to forgot mentioed methods. its under methods.

Comment: [Here's a fiddle example of the provided code working.](https://jsfiddle.net/qe8w5jbp/)